# IIS redirect www to non www using https

Tags: http, redirect, iis, https

I need some help implementing redirect.

Herewith the result I get:

```
http://example.com - https://example.com   : works
http://www.example.com - https://example.com   : works
https://www.example.com - https://example.com   : doesn't work
```

My config file:

```xml
<rule name="RedirectWwwToNonWww" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="HTTP Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: You might get some hints from FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="Force non-WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me. Unfortunately, same result.
Reason I need this is my ssl cert only supports https://example.com (non www)
Maybe easiest will be to by new cert that supports both?

Comment: This rule works for me, you can try to use failed request tracking to view the error message.